# How to get location on map and directions in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps-api-3, mapkit

I have to develop an iPhone application in which the user enters the source place and the destination place.

Something like in the first text field btm 2nd stage Bangalore, India and in the 2nd text field Whitefield, Bangalore , India.

I have to mark these places on that map and show the total distance between these 2 points.
If the user doesn't give the source place by default that will be the current location.

I have to give travel time by Car , Bike , Walk & Bus.

How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

You may take a look at [MapKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html)